# installation of Aspera connect fails

Tags: firefox, plugins, download-speed, firefox-extensions, download-manager

I have recently  installed Aspera connect plugin in firefox for downloading large packages at faster rate, but since last few days, i am unable to download any package or file using Aspera connect plugin and i dont know the reason for this.

Note: for downloading the files from human connectome project i have to use aspera connect, there is no other alternative for me to download the files.

I am using ubuntu 14.04

```
http://www.humanconnectome.org/documentation/connectomeDB/downloading/installing-aspera.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I never got aspera plugin to work correctly with Ubuntu 14.04, but I did manage to get `ascp` to work. It work much like scp, but uses the proprietary aspera protocol.

After installing the "Aspera connect plugin", just go to `~/.aspera/connect/bin/` and type `./ascp -h` for usage instructions.

I know it's not the answer you were looking for. It's just a workaround, but in my experience, the CLI client is able to do everything the desktop client does.

Disclaimer: I don't personally understand why someone would use the proprietary aspera instead of something open like "rsync", but it seems to be becoming very popular among biologically oriented web resources.

Answer (score 0):

When connect is installed, it installs a protocol handler, check it is there:

```
xdg-open fasp://initialize
```

This should start the Connect application.
If not, start manuall:

```
$HOME/.aspera/connect/bin/asperaconnect
```

In its older versions, Aspera Connect uses an HTTPS connection between the browser and connect application, using the "local.connectme.us" FQDN.
If you use a HTTP proxy, make sure that:
1- this FQDN fall in exception and goes "DIRECT"
2- this FQDN is properly resolved to 127.0.0.1
3- your browser recognized properly the certificate to this FQDN.

Try to connect tho this URL in browser when connect is started:

```
http://local.connectme.us:33003/v5/connect/info/version
https://local.connectme.us:43003/v5/connect/info/version
```

Else on command line:

```
$ curl http://local.connectme.us:33003/v5/connect/info/version
{ "version" : "3.6.2.117442" }
$ curl https://local.connectme.us:43003/v5/connect/info/version
{ "version" : "3.6.2.117442" }
```

Check the certificate is recognized:

```
openssl x509 -in $HOME/.aspera/connect/etc/localhost.crt -noout -text
```

and

```
:|openssl s_client -connect local.connectme.us:43003 2>&1
```

You can install the missing certificate authority:

```
$ curl -s
https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/GetAttachment/9
70/821027|sudo tee /usr/share/cacertificates/
mozilla/Comodo_RSA_Domain_Validation_Secure_Server_CA.crt>/dev
/null
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

or try to do:

```
$ sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Starting with version 3.9.6, connect can be used with a browser extension, if the application supports it, that do not make use of the certificate.